# ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: ssh

I failed in ssh connection to a server. Here is the output of connection

```
$ ssh -v [server]
OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-3ubuntu1, OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/tim/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to [server] [server ip] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/tim/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tim/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/tim/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`
```

Anyone know what's wrong? Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if the IP you are connecting from is showing up in `/etc/hosts.deny` on the remote server, and also check to see if you have lots of failed login attempts in `/var/log/secure`. If you do, delete those entries out of both files and you can sometime get back in.

Comment: Thanks! My IP is in hosts.deny on the remote server. So does it mean there is no way for my computer to access the server? BTW I don't have permission to see /var/log/secure.

Comment: if you can get the superuser on that computer to remove your IP from those 2 files, you should be good again. Unless it is SE linux which I know nothing about... :)

Answer (score 2):

sh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
even if the key is correct

Login via console or try login multiple times in ssh

Then check the permission of /var/log/btmp
it must be 600 
chmod 600 /var/log/btmp

Answer (score 1):

Also, try logging in without using your private key. the only way i know to do this is to temporarily move aside your private key file.